What is the most performant "32-bit only" x86 CPU?
I am thinking of building an era appropriate early/mid-2000s gaming PC. One requirement is that the CPU should not support x86-64 instruction set, only the 32-bit instructions can be used.
My guess is that the best CPU that fits the criteria is Gallatin-based Pentium 4 Extreme Edition. I can find information about 4 models of such CPU: 3.2 GHz (mPGA478B), 3.4 GHz (mPGA478B), 3.4 GHz (LGA775) and 3.467 GHz (LGA775).
Was the last model in the list the most performant "32-bit only" x86 CPU? If not, what was?

Nerdsniping: The "most powerful 32-bit only x86 system" was probably a Beowulf cluster, the first one built had 16 x486 (which are still 32bit) CPUs. But you are not actually asking for a system, you are asking for a gaming PC, for which there is no answer for this question.

I have just edited the question, and I am now asking not about a system, but specifically about a CPU. I would argue that a Beowulf cluster is a network of multiple systems, but that depends on the definition of a system.

@tpimh Well, such things are commonly called "systems", the wikipedia article does it as well: "It is a system which usually consists of one server node, and one or more client nodes ", as does the description of the original one. And in the earlier questions you also asked about graphic cards. Restricting it to a CPU definitely makes it a better question.

@tpimh I'm curious, why the restriction? While I agree, the step from 32 bit by default systems to 64 bit by default systems was a big one, but in the x86 desktop world, it was a pretty gradual shift: People bought amd64 CPUs and then used 32 bit Windows on them (and that still happens in other areas!) – simply because there wasn't that much upside to using a 2GB RAM system with a 64 bit address space, and because all 64 bit x86 (to my knowledge) are perfectly valid, compatible 32 bit x86 CPUs until you switch to 64 bit mode in software.

The restriction is entirely arbitrary: it is there just to set the upper limit for the set to choose from. I could've put the restriction as a release date (e.g. "no CPUs released after 31.12.2004"), but I think that a technical restriction works better.

@MarcusMüller: "all 64 bit x86 (to my knowledge) are perfectly valid, compatible 32 bit x86 CPUs" You're currently correct. Intel have published an outline of a simplified x86 processor that leaves out 16-bit mode and parts of 32-bit, but have not shipped any AFAIK.

@JohnDallman true, you'd need a 64 bit OS to run 32 bit software on intel X86-S CPUs, but note that the removed 32 bit instructions would not typically be these that you need to play a game on Windows XP, but things like "hardware strlen". Note that even today we can run 32 bit OSes perfectly well with 64 bit hypervisors, and "I run windows in KVM / QEMU and attach my GPU to it, so I can play games with minor loss of performance" would still allow for anything that worked 2002 to run on a (whenever X86-S hits the markets – 2026, 27, 28, maybe?) modern CPU in a hypervisor, where the CPU

really is still executing the software as originally written itself (i.e., not an emulated CPU).

Any advice on how I can improve this question to get it reopened?

@tpimh You are asking for an opinion of which processor may be best; this is a subjective question with possibly no definitive answer. Rather, it would be better to ask, for example, what was the latest and most powerful consumer 32-bit processor generally available prior to the mainstream introduction of 64-bit processors. As user3528438 mentioned, the Intel Core Duo might be one of the latest (I have a 2006 one) but probably not the fastest or most powerful.

@tpimh There is no way to make it on topic, as attributes like 'best', 'most powerful' and and even '32 bit' are up for interpretation and individual PoV, therefore opinion. (in fact the last one makes it even worse, as 64 bit CPU does not imply 64 bit code. I had my first athlon64 gaming rig in February 2004 - more than a year before there was a first windows supporting 64 bit andd only with the expensive XP Professional. Only 2006 Vista (which noone used) made 64 bit somewhat usable and it wasn't until 2009 that Win7 really made 64 bit work like today. Games until 2010 were 32 bit only.

@NoelWhitemore Yes, that's exactly what I am asking: "the most powerful processor with no support for x86-64", not an opinion, but the fact. Yes, Core Duo might be the latest, but I doubt that it will outperform P4EE, so I am asking about performance, not release date. If Atlhlon XP outperforms P4EE (which I also doubt), then that's the answer. The question might have started as "what do you think is the best", but now I edited it and now I am asking about facts, not opinions.

@Raffzahn I tried my best in editing the question to specifically not ask about opinion. The performance is measured with benchmarks, not opinions. And I defined a "32-bit x86 CPU" as one not supporting x86-64 instruction set. So Athlon XP would be a 32 bit, and Athlon 64 wouldn't, Core Duo would be 32 bit, and Prescott-based Pentium 4 wouldn't. The limitation is there specifically to exclude modern architectures and keep it about retrocomputing.

@tpimh Performance is not objective as benchmarks are always task specific, and with everyone having different tasks it's subjective which is best. Likewise, if you ask for a gaming rig, excluding the best CPUs of the time just because they have instructions isn't anything someone would have done in at the time 64 bit was seen as gimmick,the CPU was bough for itsspeed enhancement. Setting a cut off time would be way more useful than random exclusion of technology. Even more important: 32 Bit x86 is in no way retro by itself. It's just (ifatt all) older, but not retro.

You're the asker, you've got to pick a benchmark you're interested in.

If Athlon XP (or any other CPU) beats P4EE in any of the benchmarks, the question has two answers.

It's ridiculous to see all these people answer a question they agree is off-topic in the comment section!

@tpimh Why are you even asking this question if you don't have a goal in mind? It seems like you have changed it around and is now just asking to have a question out there. Was there ever an actual problem you had to solve? "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" (from dont-ask)

I think the question is both practical and answerable. I am searching for the most performant "32-bit only" x86 CPU. I have a candidate for this title: P4EE. I am asking is it really the most performant or if it is not, what is then.

"Performant" depends on what you're running. For example (one I am familiar with, not as an answer), the Pentium Pro was fast running Windows NT and dog-slow on Windows 95 (due to 16-bit code).

I distinctly remember my pentium M laptop running circles around and benchmarking better than my PIV desktops - its entirely possible the 'best' 32 bit processors never found their way to a desktop - Merom and Yonah might potentially the answer here, but they might be unsuitable for desktop use.

@JourneymanGeek Looks like Core Duo T2700 would beat any Pentium 4 in any benchmark, wow, completely overlooked this one.

PIVs were kinda jank. The funny thing was the core family was just an upgraded pentium pro based design they were working on cause it was supposed to be more efficient.  I do wonder how they compare to early 32 bit atoms... like (if I recall) the n270 too... they were XP era and you could stick a PCI GPU on em

Almost certainly the Core Duo. The Pentium 4 was a marketing gimmick. It was designed for maximum clock speed, not maximum instruction throughput, at a time when marketeers defined clock speed as the ultimate specification.

Likely the 80376. None of the CPUs you list are "32-bit only" because they also support execution of 16-bit code.

Nice one, you got my upvote. If there is not going to be any other answer, I will accept this one, because technically it's correct by definition, although completely useless to me.

You're likely to get a lot of debate on this:
Athlon XPs had a tendency for better performance per clock than a Pentium 4 (really everything here does), especially if something wasn't making heavy use of Intel-only vector instructions.
Pentium 4s reached massive clock-speeds at massive power consumption at the end.  They are probably the worst option here, but well supported.
Athlon 64s don't technically meet the requirement but would commonly be run with 32-bit OS's at first: it took a while for 64-bit Windows to become standard.  These would probably be faster than anything else in the era.
Core 1 was based on the Pentium M mobile architecture, adapted for desktop, and competed much better with Athlon XPs and Athlon 64s for reasonably efficient performance.
